# Why is IOUArray faster than StorableArray in Haskell/GHC?

Tags: arrays, haskell, ghc

Documentation of `StorableArray` says:

> It is similar to `IOUArray` but slower. Its advantage is that it's compatible with C.

I have checked it in my code, that statement is really true. But I do not understand, why. I assume that `StorableArray` is plain data without boxing and access via `poke` and `peek` is the fastest possible. Why is `IOUArray` still faster?

Comment: A `StorableArray` has to encode/decode its data every time it is written to/from the raw bytes. On the other hand, an `IOUArray` has a layout that is optimized to fit the shape of the data written to it.

Comment: Is there much to encode if I use `Word32` and `Word64` elements?

Comment: Not really, I agree. That said, the `StorableArray` path ends up in `readWord32OffAddr#` while `IOUArray` has its own dedicated primop: `readArray#`.